# Plugin menu not showing properly in wordpress

Tags: php, menu, wordpress

I made a plugin called "lsp_foo" and I made the plugin menu also. The plugin installs successfully and tables in the database is also created successfully, but the menu of the plugin is not showing to me.

I don't know what is the issue.

Here is my code:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'lsp_plugin_menu');
function lsp_plugin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('LSP FOO Pro', 'LSP FOO Pro', 'lsp_manage_options', 'lsp_options', 'wp_lsp_options', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)."/lsp_icon.png", 21);
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'LSP FOO Pro Settings', 'Manage Settings', 'lsp_manage_options', 'lsp_settings', 'wp_lsp_options');
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'Manage LSP BOO', 'Manage BOO', 'manage_boo', 'manage_boos', 'manage_lsp_boo');
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'Manage LSP GOO', 'Manage LSP GOO', 'manage_goo', 'manage_goos', 'manage_lsp_goo');
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'Plugin License', 'Activate License', 'lsp_manage_options', 'activate_license_key');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use [manage_options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_options) in capabilties Like this

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'lsp_plugin_menu');
function lsp_plugin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('LSP FOO Pro', 'LSP FOO Pro', 'manage_options', 'lsp_options', 'wp_lsp_options', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)."/lsp_icon.png", 21);
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'LSP FOO Pro Settings', 'Manage Settings', 'manage_options', 'lsp_settings', 'wp_lsp_options');
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'Manage LSP BOO', 'Manage BOO', 'manage_options', 'manage_boos', 'manage_lsp_boo');
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'Manage LSP GOO', 'Manage LSP GOO', 'manage_options', 'manage_goos', 'manage_lsp_goo');
    add_submenu_page('lsp_options', 'Plugin License', 'Activate License', 'manage_options', 'activate_license', 'activate_license_key');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing the capabilities. The third parameter of add_menu_page and add_submenu_page is the capability the user needs to access the menu. In your case they are 'lsp_manage_options', 'Manage Settings', 'Manage BOO', 'Manage LSP GOO' and 'Activate License'. To solve the problem you can add this capabilites and set them for a specific user/usergroup (Menu entry: Users -> capabilities) or you can change them to for example to 'edit_plugins', so that every user who is able to edit plugins can see the menu.

For further information take a look at:

[Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table)

[add_menu_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Comment: I don't find the solution, please can you be more specific